# Windows 10, Visual Studio, and Localization in C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, windows-10

I quite recently "upgraded" to Windows 10 from Win7, and since I'm from Finland, this caused problems with parsing DateTimes.
Quoted from similiar reddit thread:

> For the following cultures formatting a date into a string and parsing is back again fails:
>
> - Finnish (Finland)
> - Norwegian Bokmål (Norway)
> - Norwegian Bokmål (Svalbard and Jan Mayen)
> - Serbian (Cyrillic, Kosovo)
> - Serbian (Latin, Montenegro)
> - Serbian (Latin, Serbia)
> - Serbian (Latin, Kosovo)
>
> The parsing is failing because these cultures have the date separator and time separator are same and that confuse the parser as it parse the string as Time instead of Date and of course this is invalid time. Try using ParseExact to guarantee the behavior.

I'm trying to go around this problem by changing the locale of my PC, but no matter what I do, the DateTime format never changes. I tried changing the language, time zone, location, date & time formats and even keyboard language.

Is there a way I could force DateTime to use a specific culture formatting? I hear this problem has been fixed in the latest version of .NET Framework, but updating from 4.5.1 is not a good option right at this moment.

Edit: The project is huge and there are a lot of DateTime.ToString() and DateTime.Parse calls in there. I'm not supposed to replace all of them with culture specific calls but rather get DateTime.ToString() to output something that can be parsed.

Comment: There is an argument for `CultureInfo` in the `ParseExact` method? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Yes there is and I am aware that this would fix the problem. However, there are tons of DateTime.ToString() and DateTime.Parse calls throughout the project which I'm not supposed replace. Everything worked so smoothly untiln Windows 10 decided it's a good thing to use the same separator for both time and date :(